# How to change the color of my navigation?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just put up a sample of my custom theme here: http://fortmovies.com/pestcon/

Does anyone know how to change the navigation color from GRAY to WHITE? I have tried going into every div id and class within navigation and have added the "color:white;" to every one.. I have no idea where it is even causing the gray color... grrr. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#wrapper #access a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: You might as well drop `#wrapper`.

Comment: That depends on the placement of the rule.

Comment: yesss, that works! i tried #access, i guess i forgot to bring in the A and hte #wrapper... hmmm, okay thanks tho!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! will accept when it lets me in a few minutes.

Comment: @PeeHaa: You are 100% wrong. If two rules both reference #access a and specify the same property, only the later one is applied.

Comment: sab: you should accept D. Strout's answer, as it is more detailed and explains the correct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Using Firebug (an invaluable tool, I highly recommend it), it seems that the offending line is in [/pestcon/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css](http://fortmovies.com/pestcon/wp-content/themes/twentyten/style.css) on line 398:

```
#access a {
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Change `color: #aaa;` to `color: white`.

Comment: cool, thanks for the info. yeah i am using firebug but was unable to find that...... thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help. Also glad for your sake that you're using Firebug. If you're going to be doing any serious development, do yourself a favor and get to know that add-on inside and out. More and more browsers have inspectors built in, but FB tramples all over them.